# How do you convert javafx to android with cygwin?

Tags: android, shell, unix, javafx, cygwin

I have been trying to convert javafx to android using the cygwin command prompt but what ever I do I get the same error with the android sdk. The path to my android sdk is C:\Users\svond_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Here is what the terminal looks like:

```
svond_000@Spencers-PC /cygdrive/c/Users/svond_000/Documents/dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3/dalvik-sdk/samples/Ensemble8
$ bash convertJavaFXToAndroid.sh
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using empty settings script.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'C:\Users\svond_000\Documents\dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\dalvik-sdk\samples\Ensemble8\build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'Ensemble8']
Evaluating root project 'Ensemble8' using build file 'C:\Users\svond_000\Documents\dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\dalvik-sdk\samples\Ensemble8\build.gradle'.
Starting file lock listener thread.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\svond_000\Documents\dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\dalvik-sdk\samples\Ensemble8\build.gradle' line: 116

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Ensemble8'.
> Error: Path to Android SDK is invalid! [/cygdrive/c/Users/svond_000/AppData/Local/Android/sdk]

Usage: gradle createProject
    -PANDROID_SDK=<path to Android sdk>
    -PTARGET=<android platform> /optional/
    -PNAME=<project name>
    -PPACKAGE=<application package>
    -PDIR=<where to create a project>
    -DEBUG <generate vm with debug and profiling support>
    -PJFX_MAIN=<fully qualified main class to start>
    -PJFX_SDK=<path to Android sdk>
    -PJFX_APP=<path to javafx application dist dir>

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.233 secs
```

Here is the code I used (default code):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Modify the line below, point the ANDROID_SDK to the android sdk you 
# downloaded.
export /cygdrive/c/Users/svond_000/AppData/Local/Android/sdk
#
#
export HERE=${PWD}
export DALVIK_SDK=$HERE/../../
export JAVAFX_APP_DIR=$HERE/ensemble
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$PATH
export WORKDIR=$HERE/android
export PACKAGE="org.javafxports.ensemble8"
export NAME="Ensemble8Android"
export MAINCLASS="ensemble.EnsembleApp"
./gradlew --info createProject -PDEBUG -PDIR=$WORKDIR -PPACKAGE=$PACKAGE -PNAME=$NAME  \
-PANDROID_SDK=$ANDROID_SDK -PJFX_SDK=$DALVIK_SDK -PJFX_APP=$JAVAFX_APP_DIR -PJFX_MAIN=$MAINCLASS
```

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: @user2736022 I do not know; that is why I posted the question. If you find anything can you tell me.